# Insert mode before cursor position

Tags: vim

Is there a default way to jump into insert mode in Vim one character *before* the current cursor position?

I am basically looking for a way to "skip" the character the block cursor is on and then go into insert mode. Meaning I need the "i" command but a position even further to the left.

Example (Using the "|" character as the "cursor"):

```
--- NORMAL MODE ---
Hello s|tackoverflow

*Evil Keybind Pressed!*

--- INSERT MODE ---
Hello |stackoverflow
```

Can this be done by a default shortcut or should I map one? Why do I need this? Why not?

Comment: There is also the "i" command, I think that is the one you are looking for. "i" = insert before the cursor, "a" = insert (append) after the cursor

Comment: I am aware of the "i" command. I am looking for a command that drops vim into insert mode a character *before* the "i" command. Editing the question as I can see how that would be confusing the way I described it

Comment: @BastiaanvandenBerg Revised the question, my initial phrasing was not just confusing, it was utterly wrong hahah

Comment: :D no worries. I don't  know of a command for what you want, but I see that someone else came up with an example for a key mapping, I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think you can do a single key remap without overwriting a default normal mode command and of all the two key combos you could create, I don't think you can beat `hi` in normal mode.... since `h` is a default way of moving left so why learn a custom way that's only applicable in this situation?

Comment: I would have answered `hi`, but the answer in SO must be at least 30 characters

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a command, however, you can map your own:

```
:nmap <C-i> <left>i
```

Now you'll get the desired behaviour on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: Will use variation of this with one character, thanks a ton!